# Are new C++17 [[nodiscard]] warnings since Visual Studio 15.6.2 compiler update standards-compliant?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, language-lawyer, nodiscard

A recent Visual Studio Studio upgrade to version 15.6.2 included a Visual C++ compiler update which causes warnings for the following code at the `push_back` line due to `[[nodiscard]]`:

```
#include <vector>

struct [[nodiscard]] S
{
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.push_back({ 1 }); // causes warning C4834
}
```

The compiler is invoked like this (note that no high warning level needs to be specified to reproduce, but `/std:c++latest` is required, and `/permissive-` is optional):

```
cl /nologo /EHsc /permissive- /std:c++latest test.cpp
```

The warning comes from within Visual C++'s own `std::vector`-implementation code and says:

```
warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
```

*(see below for complete warning output)*

Compiler version:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.13.26128 for x64
```

My theory is that this warning is caused by:

1. Visual C++ implementing `push_back` in terms of `emplace_back`,
2. `emplace_back` returning a reference in C++17, and
3. the somewhat curious (to me) implementation of the latter function in Visual C++ if the `_HAS_CXX17` macro is set.

However, regardless of any internal library code, doesn't Visual C++ violate the standard in producing those diagnostic messages? The latest Clang and GCC versions over at wandbox.org do not produce any warnings for the same code.

I maintain that library-internal usages of `nodiscard` user types like `S` should never cause warnings, because this would render the feature unusable in practice, but the short description of `nodiscard` in §10.6.7/2 [dcl.attr.nodiscard] is a bit vague on that topic.

Or does the standard simply "discourage" such warnings, and it is all really a QoI issue, albeit a rather serious one in this case, so serious that it should probably be filed as a bug report at Microsoft?

---

Here's the complete warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vector(996): warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vector(995): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<S,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=S
        ]
test.cpp(11): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<S,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=S
        ]
test.cpp(10): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<S,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=S
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vector(1934): warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vector(1933): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<S,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Umove_if_noexcept1(S *,S *,S *,std::true_type)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=S
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vector(1944): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<S,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Umove_if_noexcept1(S *,S *,S *,std::true_type)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=S
        ]
```

Comment: Returning a reference is not sufficient to trigger a warning on `[[nodiscard]]` [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oOWIm1cCuy5afzdC), so the `emplace_back` since C++17 theory is out. Something else must be happening.

Comment: @AndyG: Thinking it over after a good night's sleep, I think that's exactly the problem. Visual C++ now produces those warnings for reference return types, both in non-member functions and in member functions (in particular, copy assignment operators...). Man, that sucks. I have the feeling that Microsoft do not consider  `[[nodiscard]]` very important at all, or else this should have broken a few regression tests.

Comment: That's disappointing. Did you test with the demo code I provided? IIRC the standard wasn't actually very clear on whether the warning should apply to reference types, although I agree with gcc and clang

Comment: @AndyG: Yes, `return_self` unfortunately produces the same warning as `return_copy` with `/std:c++latest /W3`. Interestingly, though, it does require the `/W3` flag here, in contrast to the code in my question, which will produce the warning irrespective of any warning flags.

Comment: There's no such thing as a prohibited warning. If the compiler produced a properly functioning program then it's in compliance.

Comment: @JimBalter Compliant: maybe, useable: no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, regardless of any internal library code, doesn't Visual C++ violate the standard in producing those diagnostic messages?

This question doesn't really make sense. The standard mandates that if a program violates a diagnosable rule, an implementation must issue a diagnostic. The standard doesn't say anything about disallowing diagnostics for otherwise well-formed programs.

There are many, many common compiler warnings that are diagnostics on well-formed code. Which is great! It's really a quality of implementation issue to ensure that the warnings you get are valuable. In this case, this obviously is not a valuable warning, so you should submit a bug report to Microsoft. But not because this warning violates the standard - simply because it's not a useful warning.

Comment: You are correct, I approached this issue from the wrong perspective. It's not a language-lawyer question (at least not an interesting one, because the answer is obvious, as you say), but really a question about an apparent compiler bug. Thanks!

Comment: Filed a bug report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/217312/c17-nodiscard-warnings-from-library-code.html. As always, the stupid Visual Studio report form has messed up some code formatting even though it shows correctly in the edit window, and I don't know how to fix it. My last request for help on that topic was ignored. Oh well, let's see if it accomplishes anything.

Answer (score 3):

This is not technically a MSVC bug, however warnings for `[[nodiscard]]` on reference types are *discouraged* in the standard, not prohibited.

Per our conversation, this is a reproducing example:

```
struct [[nodiscard]] S{ int i;};

template<class T>
T& return_self(T& _in){
    return _in;
}
int main() {
    S s{1};
    return_self(s);
}
```

The C++ standard has a very similar example where they discourage the warning to be elicited ([dcl.attr.nodiscard]):

```
struct [[nodiscard]] error_info { /* ... */ };
error_info &foo();
void f() { foo(); } // warning not encouraged: not a nodiscard call, because neither
                    // the (reference) return type nor the function is declared nodiscard
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the exact example from [dcl.attr.nodiscard] and get the discouraged warning.